# How to overcome automatic new line break in long VBA string?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using VBA in building a long Query in MS Access. My target is to produce Query as quoted below, which works fine when tried in Access query view (no need to scrutinize the quotes since it worked for my purpose):

However, due to its unusual length, VBA seems to have broken it automatically into 8 segments, which makes the query not executable when calling `DoCmd.RunSQL PlySQL` (`PlySQL` is the string variable to store the query below. The line breaker appeared in between a specific terms so to make query meaningless.)

I have tried to remove the newline breaker by `Replace` functions like below, but neither worked which makes me think it is a fundamentally data structure issue that I am facing. Any idea how to work around this? Thanks so much.

```
PlySQL = Replace(PlySQL, vbCrLf, "")
PlySQL = Replace(PlySQL, vbNewLine, "")
```

> SELECT [199504_hdb].Timestamp AS MTimestamp , [199504_hdb].Board_Card_1 AS BoardCard1 , [199504_hdb].Board_Card_2 AS BoardCard2 , [199504_hdb].Board_Card_3 AS BoardCard3 , [199504_hdb].Board_Card_4 AS BoardCard4 , [199504_hdb].Board_Card_5 AS BoardCard5 , [199504_hdb].No_Of_Players_Dealt_Cards AS No_of_P_DC , [199504_hdb].Players_See_Flop AS No_of_P_SeeFlop , [199504_hdb].Players_See_Turn AS No_of_P_SeeTurn , [199504_hdb].Players_See_River AS No_of_P_SeeRiver , [199504_hdb].Players_At_Showdown AS No_of_P_AtSD , [199504_hdb].Pot_BGN_Flop AS Pot_BGN_Flop , [199504_hdb].Pot_BGN_Turn AS Pot_BGN_Turn , [199504_hdb].Pot_BGN_River AS Pot_BGN_River , [199504_hdb].Pot_At_Showdown AS Pot_AtSD , [199504_hroster].Player_NickNm_1 AS Player1Nm , [199504_hroster].Player_NickNm_2 AS Player2Nm , [199504_hroster].Player_NickNm_3 AS Player3Nm , [199504_hroster].Player_NickNm_4 AS Player4Nm , [199504_hroster].Player_NickNm_5 AS Player5Nm , [199504_hroster].Player_NickNm_6 AS Player6Nm , [199504_hroster].Player_NickNm_7 AS Player7Nm , [199504_hroster].Player_NickNm_8 AS Player8Nm , [199504_hroster].Player_NickNm_9 AS Player9Nm , [199504_hroster].Player_NickNm_10 AS Player10Nm , [199504_hroster].Player_NickNm_11 AS Player11Nm , [199504_hroster].Player_NickNm_12 AS Player12Nm , [199504_pdb_Jime_xlsx].Betting_On_Flop AS P1_BetOnFlop , [199504_pdb_Jime_xlsx].Betting_On_River AS P1_BetOnRiver , [199504_pdb_Jime_xlsx].Betting_On_Turn AS P1_BetOnTurn , [199504_pdb_Jime_xlsx].Betting_Pre_Flop AS P1_BetPreFlop , [199504_pdb_Jime_xlsx].Player_Bankroll_BGN AS P1_Bankroll_BGN , [199504_pdb_Jime_xlsx].Player_Total_Betting_During_Hand AS P1_TotalBetting , [199504_pdb_Jime_xlsx].Player_Pocket_Card_1 AS P1_Card1 , [199504_pdb_Jime_xlsx].Player_Pocket_Card_2 AS P1_Card2 , [199504_pdb_Quick_xlsx].Betting_On_Flop AS P2_BetOnFlop , [199504_pdb_Quick_xlsx].Betting_On_River AS P2_BetOnRiver , [199504_pdb_Quick_xlsx].Betting_On_Turn AS P2_BetOnTurn , [199504_pdb_Quick_xlsx].Betting_Pre_Flop AS P2_BetPreFlop , [199504_pdb_Quick_xlsx].Player_Bankroll_BGN AS P2_Bankroll_BGN , [199504_pdb_Quick_xlsx].Player_Total_Betting_During_Hand AS P2_TotalBetting , [199504_pdb_Quick_xlsx].Player_Pocket_Card_1 AS P2_Card1 , [199504_pdb_Quick_xlsx].Player_Pocket_Card_2 AS P2_Card2 , [199504_pdb_Schween_xlsx].Betting_On_Flop AS P3_BetOnFlop , [199504_pdb_Schween_xlsx].Betting_On_River AS P3_BetOnRiver , [199504_pdb_Schween_xlsx].Betting_On_Turn AS P3_BetOnTurn , [199504_pdb_Schween_xlsx].Betting_Pre_Flop AS P3_BetPreFlop , [199504_pdb_Schween_xlsx].Player_Bankroll_BGN AS P3_Bankroll_BGN , [199504_pdb_Schween_xlsx].Player_Total_Betting_During_Hand AS P3_TotalBetting , [199504_pdb_Schween_xlsx].Player_Pocket_Card_1 AS P3_Card1 , [199504_pdb_Schween_xlsx].Player_Pocket_Card_2 AS P3_Card2 , [199504_pdb_^^^^^^_xlsx].Betting_On_Flop AS P4_BetOnFlop , [199504_pdb_^^^^^^_xlsx].Betting_On_River AS P4_BetOnRiver , [199504_pdb_^^^^^^_xlsx].Betting_On_Turn AS P4_BetOnTurn , [199504_pdb_^^^^^^_xlsx].Betting_Pre_Flop AS P4_BetPreFlop , [199504_pdb_^^^^^^_xlsx].Player_Bankroll_BGN AS P4_Bankroll_BGN , [199504_pdb_^^^^^^_xlsx].Player_Total_Betting_During_Hand AS P4_TotalBetting , [199504_pdb_^^^^^^_xlsx].Player_Pocket_Card_1 AS P4_Card1 , [199504_pdb_^^^^^^_xlsx].Player_Pocket_Card_2 AS P4_Card2 , [199504_pdb_aida_xlsx].Betting_On_Flop AS P5_BetOnFlop , [199504_pdb_aida_xlsx].Betting_On_River AS P5_BetOnRiver , [199504_pdb_aida_xlsx].Betting_On_Turn AS P5_BetOnTurn , [199504_pdb_aida_xlsx].Betting_Pre_Flop AS P5_BetPreFlop , [199504_pdb_aida_xlsx].Player_Bankroll_BGN AS P5_Bankroll_BGN , [199504_pdb_aida_xlsx].Player_Total_Betting_During_Hand AS P5_TotalBetting , [199504_pdb_aida_xlsx].Player_Pocket_Card_1 AS P5_Card1 , [199504_pdb_aida_xlsx].Player_Pocket_Card_2 AS P5_Card2 , [199504_pdb_argh_xlsx].Betting_On_Flop AS P6_BetOnFlop , [199504_pdb_argh_xlsx].Betting_On_River AS P6_BetOnRiver , [199504_pdb_argh_xlsx].Betting_On_Turn AS P6_BetOnTurn , [199504_pdb_argh_xlsx].Betting_Pre_Flop AS P6_BetPreFlop , [199504_pdb_argh_xlsx].Player_Bankroll_BGN AS P6_Bankroll_BGN , [199504_pdb_argh_xlsx].Player_Total_Betting_During_Hand AS P6_TotalBetting , [199504_pdb_argh_xlsx].Player_Pocket_Card_1 AS P6_Card1 , [199504_pdb_argh_xlsx].Player_Pocket_Card_2 AS P6_Card2 , [199504_pdb_brillo_xlsx].Betting_On_Flop AS P7_BetOnFlop , [199504_pdb_brillo_xlsx].Betting_On_River AS P7_BetOnRiver , [199504_pdb_brillo_xlsx].Betting_On_Turn AS P7_BetOnTurn , [199504_pdb_brillo_xlsx].Betting_Pre_Flop AS P7_BetPreFlop , [199504_pdb_brillo_xlsx].Player_Bankroll_BGN AS P7_Bankroll_BGN , [199504_pdb_brillo_xlsx].Player_Total_Betting_During_Hand AS P7_TotalBetting , [199504_pdb_brillo_xlsx].Player_Pocket_Card_1 AS P7_Card1 , [199504_pdb_brillo_xlsx].Player_Pocket_Card_2 AS P7_Card2 , [199504_pdb_jaxter_xlsx].Betting_On_Flop AS P8_BetOnFlop , [199504_pdb_jaxter_xlsx].Betting_On_River AS P8_BetOnRiver , [199504_pdb_jaxter_xlsx].Betting_On_Turn AS P8_BetOnTurn , [199504_pdb_jaxter_xlsx].Betting_Pre_Flop AS P8_BetPreFlop , [199504_pdb_jaxter_xlsx].Player_Bankroll_BGN AS P8_Bankroll_BGN , [199504_pdb_jaxter_xlsx].Player_Total_Betting_During_Hand AS P8_TotalBetting , [199504_pdb_jaxter_xlsx].Player_Pocket_Card_1 AS P8_Card1 , [199504_pdb_jaxter_xlsx].Player_Pocket_Card_2 AS P8_Card2 , [199504_pdb_rimedio_xlsx].Betting_On_Flop AS P9_BetOnFlop , [199504_pdb_rimedio_xlsx].Betting_On_River AS P9_BetOnRiver , [199504_pdb_rimedio_xlsx].Betting_On_Turn AS P9_BetOnTurn , [199504_pdb_rimedio_xlsx].Betting_Pre_Flop AS P9_BetPreFlop , [199504_pdb_rimedio_xlsx].Player_Bankroll_BGN AS P9_Bankroll_BGN , [199504_pdb_rimedio_xlsx].Player_Total_Betting_During_Hand AS P9_TotalBetting , [199504_pdb_rimedio_xlsx].Player_Pocket_Card_1 AS P9_Card1 , [199504_pdb_rimedio_xlsx].Player_Pocket_Card_2 AS P9_Card2 FROM((((((((((199504_hroster INNER JOIN [199504_hdb] ON [199504_hroster].Timestamp = [199504_hdb].Timestamp) INNER JOIN [199504_pdb_Jime_xlsx] ON [199504_hroster].Timestamp = [199504_pdb_Jime_xlsx].Timestamp) INNER JOIN [199504_pdb_Quick_xlsx] ON [199504_hroster].Timestamp = [199504_pdb_Quick_xlsx].Timestamp) INNER JOIN [199504_pdb_Schween_xlsx] ON [199504_hroster].Timestamp = [199504_pdb_Schween_xlsx].Timestamp) INNER JOIN [199504_pdb_^^^^^^_xlsx] ON [199504_hroster].Timestamp = [199504_pdb_^^^^^^_xlsx].Timestamp) INNER JOIN [199504_pdb_aida_xlsx] ON [199504_hroster].Timestamp = [199504_pdb_aida_xlsx].Timestamp) INNER JOIN [199504_pdb_argh_xlsx] ON [199504_hroster].Timestamp = [199504_pdb_argh_xlsx].Timestamp) INNER JOIN [199504_pdb_brillo_xlsx] ON [199504_hroster].Timestamp = [199504_pdb_brillo_xlsx].Timestamp) INNER JOIN [199504_pdb_jaxter_xlsx] ON [199504_hroster].Timestamp = [199504_pdb_jaxter_xlsx].Timestamp) INNER JOIN [199504_pdb_rimedio_xlsx] ON [199504_hroster].Timestamp = [199504_pdb_rimedio_xlsx].Timestamp);

Comment: VBA doesn't automatically insert newlines into long strings. Something else is going on here.

Comment: whats wrong with saving this text as a query and execute the query?

Answer (score 0):

Use the line continue character:

```
PlySQL = _
    "First long line " & _
    "Second long line " & _
    "Last long line"
```

Comment: worth mentioning, there is a limit for this line continuation (25 lines)